# CSS Animate image reveal

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a graph that I would like to animate using CSS if possible. The way I see myself doing it would be to use a mask so it starts with nothing and then slowly the mask goes across gradually revealing the graph line.

This isn't the image I'm using but will be similar:
http://jsfiddle.net/e50mnm2p/

So imagine it starts off with nothing and then from the left it will gradually reveal the green line giving the impression it's being drawn. Is there a way of doing this with masks or is there a better alternative?

```
<img src="http://www.freeimages.com/assets/183018/1830173156/graph-line-up-and-down-1-1131299-m.jpg" />
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I ended up doing:
http://jsfiddle.net/e50mnm2p/5/

HTML

```
<div class="hgInner">
    <img src="http://www.freeimages.com/assets/183018/1830173156/graph-line-up-and-down-1-1131299-m.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hgInner {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 955px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: reveal 4s ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes reveal {
    0%   {width: 0px;}
    100% { width: 100%;}
}
@keyframes reveal {
    0%   {width: 0px;}
    100% { width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: If you can use SVG to draw the line you can use the knowledge contained in this article to make a very smooth drawing animation... http://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/... Otherwise, just animate a white box on top of it, anchored to the right that decreases in width...

Comment: I'll take a look at that thanks, I was hoping there was a way to do it with CSS rather than SVGs. I can't animate a white box unfortunately as it will be sitting on a image background and the image is transparent. Thanks for the suggestions though, I'll take a look now!

Comment: Well, you could split the image up in photoshop or something... (the background) (the arrow)... and then add another copy of the background on top without the arrow in it and then do the same thing I suggested with the white box. It really depends on the graph/arrow I guess. Is it an image? Is it rendered with CSS?

Answer (score 9):

Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/e50mnm2p/3/

```
.reveal {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.reveal:after {
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:2;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}

.reveal.show:after {
    left:100%
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! This completely inspired me and made me realise what I needed to do, thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/e50mnm2p/5/

Comment: @user1788364 If you feel I helped you, please accept my answer

Comment: This works by covering the image with a white rectangle, so it's not useful if your image has a transparent background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo-element to hide the actual element. To reveal the element, animate the pseudo-element's transform property (rotate it by 90deg).

The HTML :

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS :

```
#parent {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#child {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* Pseudo-element that hides the child */
#child::after {
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 150%;
    height: 150%;
    background-color: blue;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    transition: transform linear 0.7s;
}

#child.animated::after {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

The Javascript :

```
$("#reveal-button").on('click', function() {
    $("#child").toggleClass('animated');
});
```

There's the second way to reveal hidden element explained in my blog post : http://usefulangle.com/post/37/revealing-hidden-elements-by-css-animations